# Scala REPL: How to add remote Maven repository to Scala REPL classpath?

Tags: scala, maven, read-eval-print-loop

Scala REPL is great for trying different code snippets. It would be great if one could run code using libraries from Maven repositories in Scala REPL. How to add remote Maven repository to Scala REPL classpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do everything non-trivial in SBT. In one place, the SBT `build.sbt` (or `.scala`, for advanced uses) you define all your dependencies, generate your IDE project files and run REPLs with all dependencies present in the class-path.

Answer (score 12):

You can do it, using [maven-scala-plugin](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/maven-scala-plugin/usage_console.html):

```
$ mvn scala:console
...
import com.some.dependency
```

Comment: This is so handy ! it works !! (when maven is properly configured)

Answer (score 1):

You can start from scratch - with sbt - but without build.sbt

First create sbt project:

```
sbt -sbt-create
```

Now add resolver (or other variable)

```
set resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
```

You can modify all settings. For example add dependency

```
set libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3"
```

Just for test:

```
sbt:test> console
[info] Updating ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
Welcome to Scala 2.12.7 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_201).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import org.slf4j._
import org.slf4j._

scala> val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("Test")
logger: org.slf4j.Logger = Logger[Test]

scala> val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("Test")
logger: org.slf4j.Logger = Logger[Test]
```

If you want to persist your setting just call (you can leave interactive console mode with CRTL+D)

```
sbt:test> session save
```

You output will be save in build.sbt in current directory.

For linux/mac

```
> cat build.sbt
```

For Windows (not tested)

```
> type build.sbt
```

Ouput:

```
resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"

libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test out your code just using a build.sbt file
I had to access S3 Java Code to be able to test it out on a remote server.

```
$ mkdir code-test
$ mkdir -p code-test/project
$ cd code-test
$
$ touch build.sbt
$
$ touch project/build.properties
$ echo 'sbt.version = 1.3.10' > project/build.properties
$
$ touch project/plugins.sbt
$ echo 'addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.7")' > project/plugins.sbt
```

Here I am using multiple dependencies as well as a resolver to demonstrate.

Feel free to populate your build.sbt accordingly.

Mine as a reference

```
$ cat build.sbt

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Redshift" at "http://redshift-maven-repository.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/release"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-s3" % "1.11.785",
        "com.amazon.redshift" % "redshift-jdbc42" % "1.2.41.1065"
)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Once you have appropriate dependencies in your file.

```
$ sbt

[info] Loading project definition from /home/snk01/code-test/project
[info] Loading settings for project code-test from build.sbt ...
...
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
Welcome to Scala 2.12.10 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_181).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

$ sbt:code-test>
```

This will load all the dependencies

```
$ sbt:code-test> console
```

The above line will start a scala repl with all the dependencies loaded in your classpath.

If you are starting/experimenting with something new I would suggest go with @Andrzej's method.

Credits - @Andrzej